# Qt/C++ store parent methods for callback in a QMap

Tags: c++, qt, methods, callback, qmap

I have class A with methods like A1, A2, A3, etc each accepting identical parameters (a quint64 and a Qstring).  Class A instantiates an object of class B which contains:

```
typedef void (*TCallBackFunction)(quint64, QString);
struct SCallBacks {
    TCallBackFunction success;
    TCallBackFunction failure;
};
QMap<int, SCallBacks> m_commandQueue;
void addToMap(int num, SCallBacks cb) {
  m_commandQueue[num] = cb;
}
void doCallBack(int num) {
  m_commandQueue[num].success(123,"TEST");
}
```

In class A I would call:

```
SCallBack t(1,A1);
b.AddToMap(1000,t);
b.doCallBack(1000);
```

My questions are:

1. Can A pass pointers to A methods, and expect child B to call them?
2. Is this the right way for B to call A methods?  (Signals and slots would require me to copy large amounts of code everytime I reuse the B class...so hopefully that's not the only way)
3. I'm unsure about the syntax to store the pointers to function with parameters, and how to call them - can someone fix the errors in the above?

Comment: "Signals and slots would require me to copy large amounts of code everytime I reuse the B class" - Why? Are you calling across different threads? Do you know about Qt's Copy-On-Write mechanism with Implicit Sharing? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html

Comment: Yes I'm calling across threads.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/macro-for-ptr-to-memfn.html Sigh.